# How do I adjust drag speed of an object?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, air

Ok, I am developing a game that requires the player to drag an object and place it inside of a jar.  I found it to be much easier to designate an x coordinate limitation in order to determine when the object they are dragging should simulate dropping into the jar.  The code that I have so far works perfectly.  However, the action script that is initiated when the object crosses the x coordinate limit is ignored when the players move the object too fast over the x limit.  I think that I can fix this problem by limiting how fast the object can be dragged.  Does anyone have any direction on how this can be accomplished?

Here is my code:

```
jarFront.mouseEnabled = false; jarFront.mouseChildren = false;

// animate buttons in
import fl.transitions.Tween;
import fl.transitions.easing.*;
import fl.transitions.TweenEvent;
import flash.events.Event;

var objArray:Array = new Array;

objArray.push(obj1);
objArray.push(obj2);
objArray.push(obj3);

var objPosition:Point;

function dragobj(e:Event):void {
e.currentTarget.startDrag();
objPosition = new Point( e.currentTarget.x, e.currentTarget.y);
}           
function dragobjStop(e:Event):void {
    e.currentTarget.stopDrag(); 
    e.currentTarget.x = e.currentTarget.x;
    e.currentTarget.y = objPosition.y;
    objPosition = null;
}


for (var i:uint = 0; i < objArray.length; i++) {
    objArray[i].addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, dragobj);
    objArray[i].addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, dragobjStop);
}

// Drop in jar



var HighH:int=400;
var HighW:int=400;
var LowH:int=-200; var LowW:int=0;
var HighyH:int=170;
var HighyW:int=170;
var LowyH:int=0; var LowyW:int=0;

this.addEventListener( Event.ENTER_FRAME, goJar)
function goJar( e:Event ):void
{
  if (obj1.x > 400 && obj1.x < 440) { 
        obj1.stopDrag();
           //set back or tween position 
           obj1.x = 83;
           obj1.y = -300;
           this.setChildIndex(obj1,1)
           var ct1_1:Tween = new Tween(obj1, "y", None.easeNone, obj1.y, obj1.y=Math.floor(Math.random()*(1+HighyH-LowyH))+LowyH, .2, true);
           var ct1_2:Tween = new Tween(obj1, "rotation", Bounce.easeOut, 0, 180, 1, true);
           var ct1_3:Tween = new Tween(obj1, "x", None.easeNone, obj1.x, obj1.x=Math.floor(Math.random()*(1+HighH-LowH))+LowH, .2, true);

    } else {


// keep inside jar

        if (obj1.x > -330 && obj1.x < -260) { 
        obj1.stopDrag();
           //set back or tween position 
           obj1.x = 83;
           obj1.y = -300;
           this.setChildIndex(obj1,1)
           var ct1_4:Tween = new Tween(obj1, "y", None.easeNone, obj1.y, obj1.y=Math.floor(Math.random()*(1+HighyH-LowyH))+LowyH, .2, true);
           var ct1_5:Tween = new Tween(obj1, "rotation", Bounce.easeOut, 0, 180, 1, true);
           var ct1_6:Tween = new Tween(obj1, "x", None.easeNone, obj1.x, obj1.x=Math.floor(Math.random()*(1+HighH-LowH))+LowH, .2, true);

    }
}

}
```

Also, it would be VERY helpful if there was a way to include everything below "//Drop in jar" in the array functions above so that this action script can be automatically applied to obj2 and obj3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks BotMaster, based on your direction I modified my code like so:

```
var rectangle1:Rectangle = new Rectangle(400, -665, 1156, 1052);
var rectangle2:Rectangle = new Rectangle(-376, -665, 721, 1052);
var candyPosition:Point;


function dragCandy(e:Event):void {
    if (e.currentTarget.x > 400) {
        e.currentTarget.startDrag(false, rectangle1);
        candyPosition = new Point( e.currentTarget.x, e.currentTarget.y);
        } else {
            e.currentTarget.startDrag(false, rectangle2);
            candyPosition = new Point( e.currentTarget.x, e.currentTarget.y);
            }
        }
```

Basically, what happens here:

1. If the object is at an x position greater than 400, then dragging will be constrained to rectangle1
2. Once the object has been dragged to a specific x position outside of the jar, it will be tweened inside of the jar.
3. Now that the object is in the jar, its new x position will be less than 400 and dragging will now be constrained to rectangle2.
4. Now, when the object is dragged up our of the jar and on top of the hitTestObject, it will be tweened back to a random position out side of the jar.

Answer (score 0):

You have no code in there that limits the movement of the dragged object whatsoever. If you want to limit the object position simply pass a Rectangle object to the startDrag method.

Comment: Thanks BotMaster, based on your direction, I have found a way to create two different Rectangles on the stage and determine which one to limit the object position based on the object's x position